# Unity Card Game Change Player Perspective

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and Unity.. I am trying to make a simple trading card game (tcg/ccg). For this first phase, I would like to make it to be played locally eg. **own-self versus own-self**. Would like to know how do we usually do for changing the perspective?

Eg: From the Player1's perspective as below image, once I ended my turn and pass it to player2, I would like to make it remain the same view but by showing player2's Hand card and Field card (also at the same time hide the Player1 hand card).

[image]

Below is just part of my code :

**UiController.cs**

```
   [Header("General")]
   [SerializeField] private GameObject BattleCardPrefab;

   [Header("Player Detail")]
   [SerializeField] private GameObject PlayerDeck;
   [SerializeField] private GameObject PlayerHand;

   [Header("Enemy Detail")]
   [SerializeField] private GameObject EnemyDeck;
   [SerializeField] private GameObject EnemyHand;



   private void GetUserObject(int _player)
   {
       UserDeck        = _player == 0 ? PlayerDeck.transform : EnemyDeck.transform;
       UserHand        = _player == 0 ? PlayerHand.transform : EnemyHand.transform;
   }


   public void InitDeck(int _player, List<Card> _deck)
   {
       foreach (var card in _deck)
       {
           GameObject resultCards = Instantiate(BattleCardPrefab, UserDeck);
           resultCards.GetComponent<CardDetail>().card = card;
           resultCards.GetComponent<CardDetail>().ShowCardBack(_player, resultCards, 0);
       }
   }
```

**Player.cs**

```
    public Player(int _playerIndex, string _deckName)
    {
        playerIndex = _playerIndex;
        deckName = _deckName;
    }

     public void GameStartSetUp(string _deckName){
      //initDeck and extra
      //blablabla
     }
```

**BattleManager.cs**

```
    Player player = new Player(0, "testdeck1");
    Player enemy = new Player(1, "testdeck2");

    void Start()
    {
        StartGame();
    }




    public void StartGame()
    {

        player.GameStartSetUp();
        enemy.GameStartSetUp();
    
    }
```

Please let me know if need more information from my side, mercy and thanks!

Comment: If you set up a camera position object for player1 and player2 views, you can simply switch between those views by parenting the camera to the other players view object and reseting the local position and rotation.  Then you can update the board state to show the active viewing players board state, eg. hide other players cards, show this players cards, etc.

Comment: @hijinxbassist thanks for your reply and advise. Do I  need to set up additional 2 cameras for Player1 and Player2? Or just setup additional canvas and set my default camera to it as main camera? I am not so familiar with the camera thing.

Comment: Created an answer with steps to create the scene objects and a sample script for switching the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scene Setup**

Create 2 empty game objects, "Player 1 Main View" and "Player 2 Main View".

Use the following steps for both objects:

1. Parent your camera to the object and zero out the cameras position and rotation.
2. Move that object (with the camera as child) to where the camera should be.
3. Rotate the object so the camera view looks correct.
4. Unparent the camera.
5. Repeat for other views.

**Code**

From code we parent the camera to the appropriate view object and zero out the cameras local position and local rotation.

```
public Camera viewingCamera; // <- assign your camera in inspector
public Transform player1MainView; // <- assign "Player 1 Main View" object in inspector
public Transform player2MainView; // <- assign "Player 2 Main View" object in inspector

public void EnablePlayer1View()
{
    EnableView(player1MainView);

    // Hide player 2 canvas, flip over cards, etc.
    // Show player 1 canvas, show cards, etc.
}
public void EnablePlayer2View()
{
    EnableView(player2MainView);

    // Hide player 1 canvas, flip over cards, etc.
    // Show player 2 canvas, show cards, etc.
}
private void EnableView(Transform viewObject)
{
    viewingCamera.transform.SetParent(viewObject);
    viewingCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    viewingCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
}
```

To switch the view to "Player 1", call `EnablePlayer1View()`.  For "Player 2" call `EnablePlayer2View()`.

Comment: thank you very much, I will digest and read your code , bless you~